# Run r function with C++ via Rcpp

Tags: rcpp

Trying to understand more how Rcpp works, I runned this script:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector my_fun(){
// calling rnorm()
Function f("rnorm");   

// Next code is interpreted as rnorm(n=5, mean=10, sd=2)
return f(5, Named("sd")=2, _["mean"]=10);
}
```

in order to use R function into C++ with Rcpp.
Here is the error message:

> error: 'NumericVector' does not name a type.

I checked for Rtools and it is installed, so I don't understand why it is accepting NumericVector as a type name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You failed to 
- either add the line `using namespace Rcpp;`
- or prefix the identifiers with `Rcpp::`;
- you also failed to add the `#include` for Rcpp

This works:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector my_fun(){
  // calling rnorm()
  Function f("rnorm");   

  // Next code is interpreted as rnorm(n=5, mean=10, sd=2)
  return f(5, Named("sd")=2, _["mean"]=10);
}
```

In case you are unaware, Rcpp also has a vectorised `Rcpp::rnorm()` as a C++ function -- see documentation for Rcpp Sugar.